Too high contrast with pictures in video
Does anyone know if blender has settings on how images are converted into the video strip.
I made a vacation video h264 format with original videos and photos.
When I cast the video to the TV or watch it on pc then I notice the contrast of the still pictures seams all dailed up.
When scaling images on a video strip or when keeping the original size (which is a lot higher then the 1024p video. Still images shouldn't get some internal sharpening filter, it must be a Gaussian average filter.
Is there a place we can set that?
